# How do i flip the value of a single bit?

Tags: winforms, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I' ll be honest, this is an homework i just can' t get done.
The task is to handle 8 different checkboxes by using a single byte.
The constructor of the form which contains the checkboxes takes a byte as input and sets the checkboxes to "checked" based on the input.
The flag byte is then stored somewhere and after that each time one checkbox has his status changed (from checked to unchecked and from unchecked to checked) i must change the flag byte accordingly.
So far i was only able to do the first part:

```
public Form1(byte flags)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    flags2 = flags;
    if ((flags & 0x01) >> 0 != 0) checkBox1.Checked = true; 
    if ((flags & 0x02) >> 1 != 0) checkBox2.Checked = true; 
    if ((flags & 0x04) >> 2 != 0) checkBox3.Checked = true; 
    if ((flags & 0x08) >> 3 != 0) checkBox4.Checked = true; 
    if ((flags & 0x10) >> 4 != 0) checkBox4.Checked = true;
    if ((flags & 0x20) >> 5 != 0) checkBox6.Checked = true; 
    if ((flags & 0x40) >> 6 != 0) checkBox7.Checked = true;
    if ((flags & 0x80) >> 7 != 0) checkBox8.Checked = true; 
}
```

But i really don' t know how to do a not on just 1 bit.
I thought about using additions but then the rest would change the bits to the left.
I can only use this trick on the most significative bit where a rest doesn' t have consequences.

```
private void checkBox8_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flags2 += 0x80;
}
```

For the other bits i could really use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert the bit mask:

`flags &= ~0x10`

will set bit 4 (0x10) to 0.
The `~` operator inverts all bits (8 bit example):

```
 0x10 (0001000)
~0x10 (1110111)
```

To toggle a bit use this (xor):

`flags ^= 0x10`

Using additions never works if you want to operate with bits.
For practice, I recommend to write down all numbers as bit masks:
`0x10 = 0001000` (base 2)

Comment: testing it right now, i' ll let you know if it works.                 edit: it didn' t work, the ~ operator can only be used on a byte :/

Comment: The `~` operator is defined for any integers (byte, short, int, ...)

Comment: Addition sometimes works if you're working with bits.. not if you wanted xor (aka addition without carry) of course, but for example `x & (x - 1)` (subtraction is a form of addition) to remove the rightmost 1, and some other expressions involving rightmost bits, use addition (or subtraction) in a way that makes sense on a bitvector.

Comment: @harold: you're totally right. I find it dangerous because you can only add once and then subtract once. In most cases i only set or clear a bit, mo matter how often - so the bit operations are safe.

Comment: I'm not sure that matches what I said, but sure, adding is not a very good way to set bits. And for example the identity `(x | y) == (x & ~y) + y` is not very useful since it takes more operations.

Answer (score 3):

To toggle bits, use the XOR operator (`^`):

```
flags ^= <bits>;   -or-  flags2 = flags ^ <bits>;   -e.g.-  flags ^= 0x04;
```

To set bits, use the OR operator (`|`):

```
flags |= <bits>;   -or-  flags2 = flags | <bits>;   -e.g.-  flags |= 0x08;
```

To clear bits, use the AND operator (`&`) and the NOT operator (`~`)

```
flags &= ~<bits>;  -or-  flags2 = flags & ~<bits>;  -e.g.-  flags &= ~0x08;
```

Comment: Most  descriptive answer, imho

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the variable where you have stored the initial status is flags2 then

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if(checkBox1.Checked)
       flags2 |= 1;
   else
       flags2 &= ~0xFE; 

   // ~0x2=0xFD, ~0x4=0xFB, ~0x08=0xF7, 
   // ~0x10=0xF5, ~0x20=0xEB, ~0x40=0xD7, ~0x80=0xAF
}
```

Also note that your initial test could be rewritten simply as

```
if ((flags & 0x04) != 0) checkBox1.Checked = true;
```

Comment: testing this solution right now, i' ll let you know if it works

Comment: did not work, if the addition is between two positive bits there is a rest which changes all the consecutive bits :/

Comment: well actually i failed to put it to the test, i had to do this which looks way more like your solution rather than joe' s.                 if (checkBox1.Checked) flags2 |= 0x01;
else flags2 = (byte)(flags2 & (~0x01));                                            What should i do now ? I already accepted his answer out of haste

Comment: Ah, well a case of [Fastest Gun In the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). It is up to you. You could unaccept and accept another answer if you find it is better. It happens every day. Really I am not sure what is allowed with your reps. But, in any case, you could change the accept when you have enough reps and, of course you could always upvote the partial useful answers

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can simplify your initialization code:

```
checkBox1.Checked = ((flags & 0x01) != 0);
checkBox2.Checked = ((flags & 0x02) != 0);
checkBox3.Checked = ((flags & 0x04) != 0);
checkBox4.Checked = ((flags & 0x08) != 0);
checkBox5.Checked = ((flags & 0x10) != 0);
checkBox6.Checked = ((flags & 0x20) != 0);
checkBox7.Checked = ((flags & 0x40) != 0);
checkBox8.Checked = ((flags & 0x80) != 0);
```